# React simple delete from the database - always removing last element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem when doing some React exercises with `DELETING` an item. When I do it like this, using `axios.delete` and `.filter` using a function `deleteProduct` which is activated when I confirm the action, it always takes as an `id` the id of the last element in list, so e.g. when I delete 3rd item, it deletes last, so 20th, if 20th is removed, it removes 19th next. I don't know where the problem is, because when I do `.map`, the `product.id` should be readable for each element, shouldn't it?

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import React from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import AddProduct from './AddProduct'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

function Products() {
    const axios = require('axios')
    const [products,setProducts] = useState([])

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };
    const addProduct = async (newProduct) => {
        const response = await axios.post('https://fakestoreapi.com/products', newProduct);
        console.log(response)
        setProducts([...products,response.data])
    }
    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        axios.delete('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1').then(() => setProducts(products.filter(prod => prod.id !== id)))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }

    useEffect(() =>
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "https://fakestoreapi.com/products"
        }).then((response) => setProducts(response.data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err)),[]

    )

    console.log(products)
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Add new product</h2>
            <AddProduct onSubmit={addProduct} />
            <div className="products-list">
                {products.map((product) =>
                    <div key={product.id} className="product-box">
                        <p>Id: {product.id}</p>
                        <p>Title: {product.title}</p>
                        <p>Price: {product.price}</p>
                        <p>Category: {product.category}</p>
                        <p>Image: {product.image}</p>
                        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                        <Dialog
                            open={open}
                            onClose={handleClose}
                            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                        >
                            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                                {"Usunąć ten produkt?"}
                            </DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent>
                                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                                    Ta operacja nie będzie odwracalna
                                </DialogContentText>
                            </DialogContent>
                            <DialogActions>
                                <Button onClick={handleClose}>NIE</Button>
                                <Button onClick={() => {
                                    deleteProduct(product.id);
                                    handleClose();
                                    
                                }} autoFocus>
                                    TAK
                                </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                        </Dialog>
                    </div>)}

            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
export default Products;
```

Comment: You don't use the `id` value in the HTTP DELETE request.  You always call the URL `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1`.  As for what the server-side code does with that `1` value, that's up to you I guess.

Comment: looks to me when you show the Dialog, you show ALL of them. They are all either open or not, so...do they overlap? The last one is probably always on top

Comment: The query actually doesn't matter, because it's only a simulation, it has to be deleted only locally when I've already downloaded 20 products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are always clicking the TAK button of the last item. It makes no difference which "DELETE" button you click,as the button does the same regardless of which one you click on, since it doesn't use the product.id

Easiest approach (from where you are at) is probably to change your `useState` from a boolean, to an integer and store the id of the product in open.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(-1)
```

Then pass the product.id to the handleClickOpen

```
const handleClickOpen = (id) => {
    setOpen(id);
};
...
<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => handleClickOpen(product.id)}>
    Delete
</Button>
```

Then in the render, render the dialog if the open matches product.id

```
 <Dialog
       open={open===product.id}
```

and fix up things like handleClose, too.

```
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(-1);
};
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is working how I was supposing it to work :) Btw. If I made a component for each Product and pass the id and other keys of the product, wouldn't I have such problem? I think the problem is that I don't have a component for each product and the id isn't stored anywhere. Am I right?

Comment: even if you broke out a component for each product you will still need to track which product was open. You could possibly do that within the product component with another state hook, or you could still use the parent component to track it and pass "open" as a property to the product component